# no error but no output..this is my code

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
class Blog extends Component {

  render(){
    const sidebar = (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map((post) =>
          <li key={post.id}>
            {post.title}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );

    const content = this.props.posts.map((post) =>
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {sidebar}
        <hr />
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const posts = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Hello World', content: 'Welcome to learning React!'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Installation', content: 'You can install React from npm.'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Blog posts={posts} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Please help me to get out from this error. I'm just a beginner to this. Actually this program written in function. I'm trying to change write under a class as part of my learning. But unfortunately I didn't got the output.Is it possible to add key in a class??

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:
1. You forgot to import 'component' from react.
2. You forgot to import 'ReactDOM' from react-dom.

Try following code, it will work:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Blog extends Component {

  render(){
    const sidebar = (
      <ul>
        {this.props.posts.map((post) =>
          <li key={post.id}>
            {post.title}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );

    const content = this.props.posts.map((post) =>
      <div key={post.id}>
        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div>
        {sidebar}
        <hr />
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const posts = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Hello World', content: 'Welcome to learning React!'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Installation', content: 'You can install React from npm.'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Blog posts={posts} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: but i'm actually running this program in codepen. so there no need to import , I think so...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine logically. But there might be the below problems.

1. Check if html code has a **div with id root**
2. `class Blog extends Component` where is Component coming from, try to fix it by writing `class Blog extends React.Component`

Comment: @LechuA You can accept the answer if it helped. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work